# Execute observable in sequence with RxJS, concat vs concatMap

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to perform two HTTP call in sequence but before the second one an action has to be performed using the result of the first one.

I thought that using `concat` would suffice but from what I am able to observe the action on the first HTTP is performed after the second HTTP call.

However using `concatMap` the code is performed in the order I expect but I have to ignore the result of the previous observable in the `concatMap` call.

I'm not where is the difference, I expected `concat` to be like `concatMap` to be used when I didn't need the previous Observable result but I just need to be sure that is has ended its execution.

Using the snippet below, the result I'm getting is

```
concatMap is working
do first http call
do something with http call result: 1
do second http call
concat is not working
do first http call
do second http call
do something with http call result: 1
```

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


function first() {
    console.log("do first http call");
    return Observable.of(1).do(d => {
        console.log("do something with http call result:", d)
    });
}

function second() {
    console.log("do second http call");

    return Observable.of(3);
}

console.log("concatMap is working");
first().concatMap(_ => second()).subscribe();
console.log("concat is not working");
first().concat(second()).subscribe();
```

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/rxjs/example/28035/sending-multiple-sequential-http-requests

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried with concatMap and it is working but I'm not sure what is happening. I updated the question to address this doubt